# Delete multiple collections in one command

Tags: c#, mongodb

I use MongoDB driver (C#) and kinda new with it. Is there any way or best practices to delete multiple collections in one db by one command ?
I have a lot of collections and they’re not needed anymore so I looking the way to delete many collections but without dropping all db in general ( because there’s some collections that I still need ) .

Found DeleteMany but that can be applied to collection, in my case I need something like that but what can be applied to db .

Comment: you could loop over all collections you want to drop and call `await database.DropCollectionAsync(collectionName);` or `database.DropCollection(collectionName);`

Comment: no, there is no such method